# CPACK: Specified package generator not found. CPACK_CMAKE_GENERATOR value is invalid

Tags: c++, cmake

I am trying to run `cpack`, and when I do I get the following output with this error:

```
CPack: Create package using NSIS
CPack: Install projects
CPack Error: Specified package generator not found. CPACK_CMAKE_GENERATOR value is invalid.
CPack Error: Error when generating package: draw
```

I am not setting this value, but my vscode plugin does create it and sets it to `set(CPACK_CMAKE_GENERATOR "MinGW Makefiles")` automatically when generating the `CPackConfig.cmake` and `CPackSourceConfig.cmake` files.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.14)
project(draw)
set(CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY bin)
set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Debug)
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_INCLUDE_PATH ${CMAKE_INCLUDE_PATH} "C:\\msys64\\ucrt64\\include")
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_LIBRARY_PATH ${CMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH} "C:\\msys64\\ucrt64\\lib")

# Library Settings
add_library(draw SHARED lib/file1.cpp lib/file2.cpp ...)

# Application Settings
add_executable(cli cli/main.cpp)

# target linking
target_link_libraries(draw PRIVATE ...)
target_link_libraries(cli PRIVATE draw)

include(InstallRequiredSystemLibraries)
set(CPACK_RESOURCE_FILE_LICENSE "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/License.txt")
set(CPACK_PACKAGE_VERSION_MAJOR "${Tutorial_VERSION_MAJOR}")
set(CPACK_PACKAGE_VERSION_MINOR "${Tutorial_VERSION_MINOR}")
include(CPack)
```

Building using the cmake-tools plugin works fine, the `.dll` and `.exe` both get generated, and I can run them via command line. However, when running `cpack` the above error is output.

I tried adding `set(CPACK_CMAKE_GENERATOR "NSIS")` to my `CMakeLists.txt` but that doesn't change the error message.

`cmake`/`cpack` were both installed via `MSYS2` and are located at `C:\msys64\usr\bin`. I installed `ucrt64/mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-nsis 3.09-1` version (last one) I think that is right...:

```
$ pacman -Ss nsis
mingw32/mingw-w64-i686-nsis 3.09-1
    Windows installer development tool (mingw-w64)
mingw64/mingw-w64-x86_64-nsis 3.09-1
    Windows installer development tool (mingw-w64)
ucrt64/mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-nsis 3.09-1 [installed]
    Windows installer development tool (mingw-w64)
```